# выбрать элементы с помощью регулярных выражений

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Как выбрать все файлы, кроме тех которые соответствуют данному выражению? 
Например выбрать все файлы кроме `*/folderName/subFolderName/*.*`.

```
String[] allfiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/"), "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Есть ли в RegExp метод отрицания?

Comment: Посмотрите негативный просмотр вперед/назад.
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.BE.D1.81.D0.BC.D0.BE.D1.82.D1.80_.D0.B2.D0.BF.D0.B5.D1.80.D1.91.D0.B4_.D0.B8_.D0.BD.D0.B0.D0.B7.D0.B0.D0.B4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зачем все усложнять?

```
var allfiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/"), "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);

foreach (var filePath in allfiles)
{
     if (!filePath.Contains(@"/folderName/subFolderName/"))
     {
          // код работы с filePath
     }
}
```

Либо при помощи `Linq` как ответил `ixSci`.

Comment: проблема в том что количество этих выражений(`/folderName/subFolderName/`) я не знаю

Comment: Добавьте их через `&& !filePath.Contains` либо занесите в список все выражения, и сравнивайте со списком.

Comment: Alexis, автор не получает уведомлений, если Вы явно его не упоминаете(@UserName)

Comment: @ixSci, да да, я в курсе. Просто нет смысла, он всеравно тему мониторит.

Answer (score 1):

Регулярное выражение Вам не поможет, т.к. `GetFiles` их не поддерживает. Вашу задачу можно решить, например, так:

```
String[] allfiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/"), "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
allfiles = allFiles.Where(name => !name.Contains("/folderName/subFolderName/").ToArray();
```

Comment: a разве  это не регулярное выражение `"*.*"` ?

Comment: Это паттерн поиска.

Comment: @ArsenArm, это wildcards.